# What happens when a exception occurs in exception block

Tags: exception, plsql

suppose in my procedure, error occurred and it went to exception block.
while entering the logs for error occurred another error takes placein exception block itself.

What happens then ...

Comment: it would be better if you can add some code snippet for us to understand your question better.

Comment: the same behave as usual the exception will be thrown to the caller of that func/proc or your programm will be finished with exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find out is surely to try it?

```
declare
   dummy integer;
begin
   select 99 into dummy from all_objects; -- Will raise TOO_MANY_ROWS
exception 
   when too_many_rows then
      select 77 into dummy from dual where 2=3; -- Will raise NO_DATA_FOUND
end;    
/
```

When you run that you will get:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

Comment: Got it thanks..!!! Means still it will execute and throw exception for error in exception block... but nothing for the error in main block ....TOO_MANY_ROWS gets skipped and we wont be able to track what happened in main block... Can you help with that ... OR can we use PRAGMA autonomous transaction for that..

Comment: I don't think so.  If you catch the first exception then it is up to you to log it or raise it or whatever.  If you try to log it and your logging code fails, you have lost the original exception.  But why would your logging fail?  Need to make it robust!

Comment: PRAGMA autonomous transaction would be the equalviant of "PRAGMA create untraceable bug here". You would get neither the original error nor the secondary one.